# How to delete the Log statements in my project using proguard rules?

Tags: android, security, proguard, obfuscation

I need to delete all the Log statement inside my project using proguard.

Previously i was using the default proguard-android.txt file for obfuscating and didn't find any Success. i was able to see the Log statement when using any apk decompiler.

The rules were -

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {

    public static int v(...);
    public static int i(...);
    public static int w(...);
    public static int d(...);
    public static int e(...); }
```

After searching for a while i came to the answer which quoted that i need to use `'proguard-android-optimize.txt'` because by default the optimize is not enabled.

But again i am getting error below -

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Form-encoded method must contain
>   at least one @Field.

I think the proguard must have deleted the

> @FormUrlEncoded

in retrofit2.

Tell me where am i wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this Proguard setting:

`-keepattributes *Annotation*`